# Group Bar Chart in R - Improper Y Axis

Tags: r, charts, bar-chart, plotly

I'm trying to build a grouped bar chart in R. I have pasted the dataframe below. I have been using **plotly** to build the chart. The problem is, the numbers on Y axis are not proper, as in they do not increase in ascending order. I've also posted an image of graph formed.

Can someone please point out, where I'm going wrong?

### Dataframe

```
chart.supp.part.defect.matrix


     Supplier PaintMarking45 Seal78 AirConditioning57 Engine34 CargoCompartment543 Insulation11
1     HJRU              8   <NA>              <NA>        1                <NA>         <NA>
2     DJDU           <NA>      1              <NA>     <NA>                <NA>         <NA>
3     DEF7           <NA>      3                54     <NA>                <NA>         <NA>
4      A23           <NA>   <NA>              <NA>        7                <NA>         <NA>
5      A52              3   <NA>              <NA>     <NA>                   2         <NA>
6     FJUE             65   <NA>                 1     <NA>                <NA>           11
7      A31           <NA>      1                 5     <NA>                <NA>         <NA>
8     DJHD           <NA>   <NA>              <NA>     <NA>                <NA>         <NA>
9      A38              4   <NA>                22     <NA>                <NA>         <NA>
```

### Code to build chart

```
 title <- paste( "Supplier vs Defect")

p3 <- plot_ly(chart.supp.part.defect.matrix, x = ~Supplier, y = ~PaintMarking45, type = 'bar', name = 'Paint/Marking-45') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Seal78,name = 'Seal-78') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~AirConditioning57,name = 'Air conditioning - 57') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Engine34,name = 'Engine-34') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~CargoCompartment543,name = 'Cargo compartment-543') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Insulation11 ,name = 'Insulation -11') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Insulation6,name = 'Insulation-6') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Engine11,name = 'Engine-11') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Propulsion32,name = 'Propulsion-32') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Defect Count'), barmode = 'group') %>%
  layout(title = title)

ggplotly(p3)
```

### Chart

[image]

### Edit

```
dput(chart.supp.part.defect.matrix)


structure(list(Supplier = structure(c(9L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 
2L, 7L, 3L), .Label = c(" A23", " A31", " A38", " A52", " DEF7", 
"DJDU", "DJHD", "FJUE", "HJRU"), class = "factor"), PaintMarking45 = structure(c(4L, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, NA, NA, 2L), .Label = c("3", "4", "65", "8"
), class = "factor"), Seal78 = structure(c(NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("1", "3"), class = "factor"), AirConditioning57 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, 4L, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L), .Label = c("1", "22", "5", "54"
), class = "factor"), Engine34 = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, 2L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("1", "7"), class = "factor"), 
    CargoCompartment543 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), .Label = "2", class = "factor"), Insulation11 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "11", class = "factor"), 
    Insulation6 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA), .Label = "7", class = "factor"), Engine11 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("54", "8"), class = "factor"), 
    Propulsion32 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1L), .Label = "2", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Supplier", 
"PaintMarking45", "Seal78", "AirConditioning57", "Engine34", 
"CargoCompartment543", "Insulation11", "Insulation6", "Engine11", 
"Propulsion32"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput(chart.supp.part.defect.matrix)` to your question?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Done. Made the edit

Comment: Problem is that your values are stored as factors, not numeric. This probably occurred when you read the data into R (using `read.table` perhaps?) and did not specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. You might also need to specify `na.strings` (what character represents missing values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Adam Spannbauer's approach you can also force Plotly to interpret the data as numbers by setting the `yaxis` `type` to `linear`

```
layout(yaxis=list(type='linear'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as @neilfws mentioned in a comment the issue is that your `y` access data is being built off of factors.  You can attempt to fix this on your data read (as @neilfws mentioned) or coerce your data to numeric before plotting.  Below is how you can do the latter.

```
chart.supp.part.defect.matrix[,2:10] <- lapply(chart.supp.part.defect.matrix[,2:10], as.numeric)

p3 <- plot_ly(chart.supp.part.defect.matrix, x = ~Supplier, y = ~PaintMarking45, type = 'bar', name = 'Paint/Marking-45') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Seal78,name = 'Seal-78') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~AirConditioning57,name = 'Air conditioning - 57') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Engine34,name = 'Engine-34') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~CargoCompartment543,name = 'Cargo compartment-543') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Insulation11 ,name = 'Insulation -11') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Insulation6,name = 'Insulation-6') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Engine11,name = 'Engine-11') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Propulsion32,name = 'Propulsion-32') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Defect Count'), barmode = 'group') %>%
  layout(title = title)

p3
```

Additionally, you don't need to call `ggplotly` in this case.  That function is only needed when you want to build your plot using `ggplot2` and then add plotly's interactivity to the ggplot object.

Comment: You are correct. Unfortunately I can select only one correct answer. Thanks for your help